# Can we give function return in value field in hidden type field?

Tags: php, html

In hidden type text area can we give function in the value fileld.

Can anyone explain what does the following two lines do?

```
echo "<INPUT TYPE=\"HIDDEN\" NAME=\"NVOAction\" VALUE=\"Authenticate()\">\n";
        echo "<INPUT TYPE=\"HIDDEN\" NAME=\"NVORedirect\" VALUE=\"redirectwebsite.com\">\n";
```

Below is the full code.

```
echo "<HTML>\n";
        echo "<HEAD>\n";
        echo "<TITLE>Name</TITLE>\n";
        echo "<META http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\">\n";
        echo "<META NAME=\"pragma\" CONTENT=\"no-cache\">\n\n";
        echo "</HEAD>\n";

        echo "<BODY bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" text=\"#000000\" onLoad=\"javascript:document.nvoForm.submit();\">\n\n";

        echo "<FORM NAME=\"nvoForm\" METHOD=\"POST\" ACTION="website.com">\n";
        echo "<INPUT TYPE=\"HIDDEN\" NAME=\"NVOAction\" VALUE=\"Authenticate()\">\n";
        echo "<INPUT TYPE=\"HIDDEN\" NAME=\"NVORedirect\" VALUE=\"redirectwebsite.com\">\n";
        echo "<INPUT TYPE=\"HIDDEN\" NAME=\"NVOTarget\" VALUE=\"_top\">\n";
        echo "<INPUT TYPE=\"HIDDEN\" NAME=\"nssaccount\" VALUE="account">\n";
        echo "<INPUT TYPE=\"HIDDEN\" NAME=\"nssuser\" VALUE="user">\n";
        echo "<INPUT TYPE=\"HIDDEN\" NAME=\"nsspassword\" VALUE="pass">\n";

        echo "</FORM>\n\n";
        echo "</BODY>\n";
        echo "</HTML>\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly and your function return a string, you would be able to do:

```
echo "<INPUT TYPE=\"HIDDEN\" NAME=\"NVOAction\" VALUE=\"".Authenticate()."\">\n";
```

**Note:**

As you can see with SO's code highlighting, you have a few lines that will probably break, because you don't escape your attribute quotations, like on this line for instance:

```
echo "<FORM NAME=\"nvoForm\" METHOD=\"POST\" ACTION="website.com">\n";
```

It needs to be:

```
echo "<FORM NAME=\"nvoForm\" METHOD=\"POST\" ACTION=\"website.com\">\n";
```

**Update**
I re-read your question, so here is an update of my answer.

```
// This line will (when fixed according to above) create an HTML form input, 
// and give it the value of whatever is returned by the Authenticate() method 
echo "<INPUT TYPE=\"HIDDEN\" NAME=\"NVOAction\" VALUE=\"Authenticate()\">\n";
// This line will create an HTML form input and give it the 
// value of redirectwebsite.com
echo "<INPUT TYPE=\"HIDDEN\" NAME=\"NVORedirect\" VALUE=\"redirectwebsite.com\">\n";
```